# glDrawElements not working with STL vector

Tags: c++, opengl, vector, stl

In my current project I just changed every array pointer of my Mesh class to an STL vector, as I experienced problems when using pointers to `std::vector::front()` after the original vectors where discarded as they were defined locally inside a function. So far it's working fine, but OpenGL won't even draw a simple cube using Vertex Arrays.

I've reduced my rendering function to the following for testing purposes:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
//replacement for the deprecated glLookAt, which is unavailable in Mesa 10.1 (what I use)
util_compat_gluLookAt(posX+cx,posY+cy,posZ+cz, posX,posY,posZ, 0,1,0);

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(posX,posY,posZ);
glRotatef(spectator_longitude*180/M_PI, 0,1,0);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, &cube.getColors().front());
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &cube.getVertices().front());
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, cube.getIndices().size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, &cube.getIndices().front());

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

glPopMatrix();

//These WCS axes are drawn without problem
glLineWidth(3);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glColor3f(1,0,0);
glVertex3f(0,0,0);
glVertex3f(100,0,0);
glColor3f(0,1,0);
glVertex3f(0,0,0);
glVertex3f(0,100,0);
glColor3f(0,0,1);
glVertex3f(0,0,0);
glVertex3f(0,0,100);
glEnd();

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(screen);
```

The vectors (and the mesh object, from which `player` inherits) are defined in a header included in the gameloop file:

```
//  vertices
std::vector<float> vertices {
    -5,0,-5,
    5,0,-5,
    -5,10,-5,
    -5,0,5,
    5,10,-5,
    5,0,5,
    -5,10,5,
    5,10,5
};
//  Color buffer
std::vector<unsigned byte> colors {
    0,0,0,255,
    255,0,0,255,
    0,255,0,255,
    0,0,255,255,
    255,255,0,255,
    255,0,255,255,
    0,255,255,255,
    255,255,255,255
};
//  Vertex index buffer
std::vector<unsigned int> indices {
    0,1,4,2,
    0,2,6,3,
    0,3,5,1,
    1,4,7,5,
    5,7,6,3,
    2,6,7,4
};
```

The methods `cube.getVertices()`, `cube.getColors()` and `cube.getIndices()` return STL vectors containing the vertices (as float), the colors (as unsigned byte) and the index list (as unsigned int).

According to the GDB debugger, these vectors contain the correct values. Since I'm compiling with `--std=c++11`, the vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous.

The same rendering process, only using arrays (resp. pointers to their first elements) instead of vectors, worked without any problems. Now only the lines at the WCS axes are drawn. Moving the cube around (with SDL event handling) still works, the `gluLookAt` replacement function does it's work as intended.

What could be the problem here? I've googled a lot, but none of the suggested solutions worked for me.

**Edit:** I just noticed the cube is drawn sporadically. This means it appears randomly for about one or two frames and then vanishes again. I managed to see it twice in about a minute (while moving it around all the time)

**Edit 2:** It is definitely not a driver issue, since the described behavior appears both when using `xserver-xorg-video-ati` (XOrg XServer AMD/ATI driver) and when using `fglrx` (AMD Catalyst driver for XServer)

**Edit 3:** A screenshot of the cube appearing for one frame, however, it's not displayed as a cube... But still the vectors contain the correct values...
[image]

Comment: How do you put these values in your vector?

Comment: _'after the original vectors where discarded as the weren't needed any more.'_ Huh?

Comment: Currently the vectors are hardcoded in a header file. Another object (removed from the rendering for debugging) is loaded form a file. Both contain the intended values. `after the original vectors where discarded as the weren't needed any more.`-> I created a Stanford PLY loader which used local vectors and then returned pointers to their first entries. After leaving the loader, the vectors, being defined inside the loader function, were freed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace every `std::vector get...()` with `std::vector const& get...()` and it works.

In the first case, a copy of the vector is created, which is only needed to be passed to OpenGL, then it's discarded. So the pointer to the first vector element now points to garbage.

By replacing it with the second declaration, a reference to the original vector is returned, so the data will stay untouched after the copy is discarded, because there still are the originals.